# Visual Studio 2013 Enable Migrations

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

At first i thought there was something wrong with my operating system, maybe my visual studio instance but for the second time now on 2 separate solutions, every time i execute `Enable-Migrations`, or `Add-Migration Initial` or `Update-Database` my visual studio crashes and restarts.

If i need updates, there is usually a notification when i start visual studio but there has been none, but also i haven't used those commands in a while.

Has anyone else been experiencing this with Visual Studio 2013?

Answer (score 2):

Are you write the project name?

For example:

Enable-Migration -ProjectName MyProjectName

Add-Migrations -ProjectName MyProjectName -Name InitializeSQL

Update-Database -ProjectName MyProjectName

Link: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

HappyCoding!